# A function is lambda-2-definable iff it is HG computable and provably type correct in lambda-PRED2

Tags: lo.logic, pl.programming-languages, computability, type-theory, lambda-calculus

I'm having a problem regarding Theorem 5.4.40.3 of Barendregt's *Lambda calculi with types* (1992), a chapter in Handbook in logic in computer science. (I'm referring to the [PostScript version](http://ttic.uchicago.edu/~dreyer/course/.../barendregt.pdf) available on the Web.)

The theorem states that a function is $\lambda$2-definable iff it is HG (Herbrand-Goedel) computable and provably type correct in $\lambda$PRED2.  The author delegates the proof to a proceeding in FOCS, i.e., *Reasoning about functional programs and complexity associated with type disciplines* (1983) by Leivant.  The corresponding theorem in the proceeding is Theorem 3.1 and Corollary 3.2, although they are stated in terms of provable type-correctness in $\lambda$2, not in $\lambda$PRED2.

The first problem I'm running into is that the definition of HG computability by Barendregt doesn't make sense.  IMHO, the equation in Definition 5.4.39.1 should be replaced by
$$
\mathit{HG} \vdash p:(f_n(t^\sim) =_L (f(t))^\sim).
$$

Assuming this, I tried to prove the equivalent of Theorem 3.1 (Leivant) in terms of $\lambda$PRED2, but in vain.  Leivant's proof is informal and I have hard times formalizing it. (By using Barendregt's notation, I'm pretty sure that if $B$ is the proof of $f$'s type correctness then $[B]$ is a $\lambda$2-term that represents $f$, but I am unable to prove this.)  Besides, his proof deals with only one direction of the equivalence (provably type correct $\Rightarrow$ $\lambda$2-definable) and the rest is left unstated.  I suppose the opposite direction involves the formalization of SN, but I am unsure.

I would be the most grateful for detailed explanation of Theorem 5.4.40.3 by Barendregt.

Comment: I'm not finding a theorem 3.4.40.3. Care to give a page number?

Comment: @cody Thank you for pointing out the typo; it's actually 5.4.40.3, on page 163 (in the PostScript file).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My first advice is to take a look at chapter 15 of Girard, Lafont & Taylor [Proofs & Types](http://www.paultaylor.eu/stable/prot.pdf). In it, a weaker theorem is proved, but the basic ideas are quite similar, and the exposition should be simpler.

Second: Provably type correct is a bit of a misnomer. The property looks more like *definability* or *accessibility*. In a nutshell it expresses

$$ \forall t_1,\ldots t_n,\ \mathrm{Ind}(t_1) \wedge \ldots\wedge\mathrm{Ind}(t_n) \Rightarrow \mathrm{Ind}(f(t_1,\ldots, t_n))$$
where $\mathrm{Ind}(t)$ means the term $t$ is *inductive*, that is, built up from constructors. Being inductive is essentially being defined as an element of the inductive type, which makes the above property a statement about definability.

Third: You are correct, if $B$ proves that $f$ is type correct, then $[B]$ is the definition of $f$. Work through an example first: If $\mathrm{add}: \mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{N}$, then the statement of type correctness is:

$$ \forall x\ y,\ \mathrm{Ind}_{\mathbb{N}}(x)\rightarrow\mathrm{Ind}_{\mathbb{N}}\rightarrow \mathrm{Ind}_{\mathbb{N}}(\mathrm{add}(x, y))$$
in $\lambda\mathrm{PRED}_2$, which, erased, gives
$$ \mathrm{N}\rightarrow\mathrm{N}\rightarrow\mathrm{N}$$
in $\lambda_2$ (with $\mathrm{N}=\Pi X:*.X\rightarrow(X\rightarrow X)\rightarrow X$) which is exactly the right type for $\mathrm{add}$! So at least the types add up. Checking that the proof of type correctness of $\mathrm{add}$ gives you a good definition is more tedious, but Leivant gives the details.

Fourth: you are correct that (1 way of seeing) the converse requires examining the proofs of strong normalization. For each function definition in $\lambda_2$, you can "decorate" it into a proof of type correctness in $\lambda\mathrm{PRED}_2$, essentially using the "theorem for free" that comes with the type. A really nice exposition is Wadler, [The Girard-Reynolds isomorphism](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/wadler/papers/gr2/gr2.pdf), which is a highly suggested read for anyone in the field.

Fifth: I think you are correct in your correction of 5.4.39.

---

**Edit**: Elaboration on the 4th point:

Wadler defines, among other things, the *Reynolds embedding* from $\lambda_2$ to $\lambda\mathrm{PRED}_2$ with higher-order functions (Figure 4). This embeding sends a type to a proposition (the *parametricity theorem*) and sends a well tyepd term to a proof of parametricity of that same term.

The theorem you get implies "type correctness" of the defined function rather trivially. In fact I think Wadler treats this in detail in Section 5, and treats the $\mathrm{add}$ example in the appendix. The only subtle point is that the function is not directly defined over the inductive type, rather it takes the type and constructors as *arguments*.

At this point I really have to suggest you work through some examples.

Comment: Is it possible for you to elaborate on the fourth point on the converse?  I don't understand what part of the Wadler's work you introduced to me gives the result.

Comment: I edited my answer to try to elaborate.